# What does the target mean in fetch_20newsgroups

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Sorry for asking dumb question. I'm new to the fetch_20newsgroup. I have printed out the newsgroups_train.target but i still don't get it what it means. Also, I have taken a look at the doc of sklearn. It said that target is a target label? Please someone tell me what does it mean thanks!

```
print(newsgroups_train.target)
[7 4 4 ... 3 1 8]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newsgroups_train.target` returns the label corresponding to the features. It represents the ids of the newsgroup your are aiming to predict.

You can convert them to their respective names using `newsgroups_train.target_names` as follows :

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import numpy as np

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')

X, y = newsgroups_train.data, newsgroups_train.target

print(np.array(newsgroups_train.target_names)[y])
```

which output:

```
['rec.autos' 'comp.sys.mac.hardware' 'comp.sys.mac.hardware' ...
 'comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware' 'comp.graphics' 'rec.motorcycles']
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! I still don't get it what does the output [7 4 4 ... 3 1 8] mean when I newsgroups_train.target?

Comment: Those are the ids of the newsgroup, for example 0 is `alt.atheism`, 1 is `comp.graphics`, etc.

Comment: Oh I see, so the maximum of the id is 19 right? I mean we only have 20 groups.

Comment: Yes, as the name of the dataset :)